# Get the argument value of a directive in a controller

Tags: angularjs, attributes, directive

I would like to create a directive and use the argument in my controller:

```
<body ng-app="tstApp">
    <navigationbar tst="hello">
    </navigationbar>
</body>
```

For this I create a directive and its controller:

```
navigationBar = {};
navigationBar.directives = {};
navigationBar.controllers = {};

navigationBar.directives.navigationbar = function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            t1: '@tst',
            t2: '=tst',
            t3: '&tst'
        },
        templateUrl: "common/navigation_bar/navigation_bar.tpl.html",
        controller: "NavigationBarController"
    }
};

navigationBar.controllers.NavigationBarController = function ($scope, Api) {
    console.log($scope);
    console.log($scope.t1);
    console.log($scope.t2);
    console.log($scope.t3);
};

testApp.directive(navigationBar.directives);
testApp.controller(navigationBar.controllers);
```

In the console I got this:

```
Scope {$id: "003", $$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$prevSibling: null, $$nextSibling: null…}
$$asyncQueue: Array[0]
$$childHead: Child
$$childTail: Child
$$destroyed: false
$$isolateBindings: Object
$$listeners: Object
$$nextSibling: Child
$$phase: null
$$prevSibling: null
$$watchers: Array[9]
$id: "003"
$parent: Scope
$root: Scope
nav: Object
t1: "hello"
t2: undefined
t3: function (locals) {
this: Scope
__proto__: Object
```

and:

```
undefined navigation_bar.js:33
undefined navigation_bar.js:34
function (locals) {
                  return parentGet(parentScope, locals);
                }
```

I would like to understand why the **console.log($scope.t1);** doesn't display the value as it is in the scope->t1: "hello"

Thank you for your help,

Julio

**Add information:**

If I replace the templateUrl by:

```
template: "Scope Id: {{$id }}, t1: {{ t1 }}"
```

I got:

```
Scope Id: 003, t1: hello
```

If I put the some trace in the controller like this:

```
console.log('Scope Id: ' + $scope.$id +  ', t1: ' + $scope.t1);
```

I got:

```
Scope Id: 003, t1: undefined
```

So the scope is the same and is shared. But why I can't reach the t1 value in the controller. Should I evaluate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@` scoping only set the value to the isolated scope to the plain attribute value, which is always a string. It is not evaluated in any way.

You can read more about the scoping object in the [AngularJS Directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) documentation under the *Directive Definition Object* section.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added more information in my question. The scope is well shared as I defined the Controller in the Directive. The thing is that I am still not able to use the argument value. I certainly missed a point in the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

I got the point.

**1. Why undefined.**

I think the value is undefined because during the construction of the controller the binding is not done.

**2. How to get the value**

As the attribute is passed with the **@**, we need ton define an observer to watch the binding. For this I added the link attribute:

```
    link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
        $attr.$observe('tst', function(value){
            console.log('value', value)
            $scope.nav.selection = value
        }
        );
    }
```

I hope this is the best way.